# How to properly set rendering Rmarkdown to pdf?

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown

I use Rmarkdown to generate reports and if my line is too long it is usually cut after rendering.

Is there a way to fix it?

I attach a screenshot in order better explain my issue.

[image]

Comment: This can help: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/text-width.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the chunk option `tidy=TRUE` to automatically insert line breaks in the code.

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r, tidy = TRUE}
c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0)
```
````

The linebreaks are inserted by `formatR::tidy_source()`. See https://yihui.org/knitr/options/#code-decoration for more details.

```r
chunk_content <- "c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0)"
formatR::tidy_source(text = chunk_content, width.cutoff = 30)
#> c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0,
#>     1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
#>     0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,
#>     9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,
#>     8, 9, 0)
```

Comment: Option tidy=TRUE did not help I am not sure maybe it is also OS related stuff. I use Rstudio on Windows with MikiTex installed to rencer to PDF.

Comment: So I suppose the solution worked at the end since the answer was accepted? Could you  clarify why this wasn't working initially?